# MyST-Parser: Auto linking / linkifying references to bug tracker issues

Tags: python-sphinx, docutils, python-markdown

- I use [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/) w/ [MyST-Parser](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/) for markdown, **and**
- I want [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/autolinked-references-and-urls#issues-and-pull-requests) or [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#gitlab-specific-references)-style auto linking (linkfying) for references.

Is there a way to have MyST render the reference:

```markdown
#346
```

In docutils-speak, this is a [`Text`](https://pydoc.dev/docutils/latest/docutils.nodes.Text.html) node ([example](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/dev/hacking.html#:%7E:text=has%20children%3A%20A-,text%20node,-(%22My%20%22)%2C%20an%20emphasis))

And behave as if it was:

```markdown
[#346](https://github.com/vcs-python/libvcs/pull/346)
```

So when rendered it'd be like:

[#346](https://github.com/vcs-python/libvcs/pull/346)

*Not* the custom role:

```markdown
{issue}`1` <- Not this
```

Another example: Linkifying the reference `@user` to a GitHub, GitLab, StackOverflow user.

## What I'm currently doing (and why it doesn't work)

Right now I'm using the canonical solution [docutils](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/) offers: custom [roles](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/roles.html).

I use [sphinx-issues](https://github.com/sloria/sphinx-issues) ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-issues/)), and does just that. It uses a sphinx setting variable, [`issues_github_path`](https://github.com/sloria/sphinx-issues/tree/3.0.1#:%7E:text=user%20or%20organization)-,issues_github_path,-%3D%20%22sloria/marshmallow) to parse the URL:

e.g. in Sphinx configuration `conf.py`:

```py
issues_github_path = 'vcs-python/libvcs'
```

- reStructuredText:

  ```
  :issue:`346`
  ```
- MyST-Parser:

  ```markdown
  {issue}`346`
  ```

**Why custom roles don't work**

Sadly, those aren't bi-directional with GitHub/GitLab/tools. If you copy/paste MyST-Parser ->  GitHub/GitLab or preview it directly, it looks very bad:

- Example of [`CHANGES`](https://github.com/vcs-python/libvcs/blob/v0.12.3/CHANGES#development):

  [image: Example of myst-style sphinx-issue markdown previewed]
- Example issue: https://github.com/vcs-python/libvcs/issues/363

What we want is to just be able to copy markdown including `#347` to and from.

## Does a solution already exist?

Are there any projects out there of docutils or sphinx plugins to turn `@username` or `#issues` into links?

- sphinx (at least) can demonstrable do so for custom roles - as seen in sphinx-issues usage of `issues_github_path` - by using project configuration context.
- MyST-Parser has a [linkify](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/optional.html#linkify) extension which uses [linkify-it-py](https://github.com/tsutsu3/linkify-it-py)

  This can turn `https://www.google.com` into https://www.google.com and not need to use `<https://www.google.com>`.

Therefore, there may already be a tool out there.

## Can it be done through the API?

The toolchain for myst, sphinx and docutils is robust. This is a *special case*.

This needs to be done at the [`Text`](https://pydoc.dev/docutils/latest/docutils.nodes.Text.html) node level. [Custom role](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/howto/rst-roles.html) won't work - as stated above - since it'll create markdown that can't be copied between GitLab and GitHub issues trivially.

**The stack:**

[MyST-Parser API](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.17.2/api/index.html#api-main) ([Markdown-it-py API](https://markdown-it-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/markdown_it.html)) > [Sphinx APIs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/index.html#apis-used-for-writing-extensions) ([MySTParser + Sphinx](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.17.2/sphinx/index.html)) > [Docutils API](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/markupapi.html)

At the time of writing, I'm using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html) 4.3.2, [MyST-Parser 0.17.2](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.17.2/), and [docutils](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/) 0.17.1 on python 3.10.2.

**Notes**

- For the sake of an example, I'm using an open source project of mine that is facing this issue.
- This is only about autolinking issues or usernames - things that'd easily be mappable to URLs. [autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) code-linking is out of scope.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html ?

Comment: From the looks of it, it'd have the same problem as sphinx-issues - reliance on a docutils role - it wouldn't be able to parse #123 by itself.

Comment: Did you only look, and not try? Some custom roles are implemented better than others.

Comment: @StevePiercy Can you please read the question? It says to link things like #1 (text), _not_ like `{issue}\`1\`` (custom role), since this is already doable easily.

Comment: I further clarified the question.

Comment: In theory, you can write your own docutils transform class or sphinx plugin which will turn any `#123` text into the link you expect. I'm not aware of any plugin doing that. That said I don't know how the MyST parser is integrated into the stack, so it may be little harder compared to plain rst.

Comment: See https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/transforms.html and https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a (defunct) project that does this: [sphinxcontrib-issuetracker](https://github.com/ignatenkobrain/sphinxcontrib-issuetracker).

I've rebooted it:

*conf.py*:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

cwd = Path(__file__).parent
project_root = cwd.parent

sys.path.insert(0, str(project_root))
sys.path.insert(0, str(cwd / "_ext"))

extensions = [
    "link_issues",
]

# issuetracker
issuetracker = "github"
issuetracker_project = "cihai/unihan-etl"  # e.g. for https://github.com/cihai/unihan-etl
```

*_ext/link_issues.py*:

```py
"""Issue linking w/ plain-text autolinking, e.g. #42

Credit: https://github.com/ignatenkobrain/sphinxcontrib-issuetracker
License: BSD

Changes by Tony Narlock (2022-08-21):
- Type annotations

  mypy --strict, requires types-requests, types-docutils

  Python < 3.10 require typing-extensions
- TrackerConfig: Use dataclasses instead of typing.NamedTuple and hacking __new__
- app.warn (removed in 5.0) -> Use Sphinx Logging API

  https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/logging.html#logging-api
- Add PendingIssueXRef

  Typing for tracker_config and precision
- Add IssueTrackerBuildEnvironment

  Subclassed / typed BuildEnvironment with .tracker_config
- Just GitHub (for demonstration)
"""
import dataclasses
import re
import sys
import time
import typing as t

import requests
from docutils import nodes
from sphinx.addnodes import pending_xref
from sphinx.application import Sphinx
from sphinx.config import Config
from sphinx.environment import BuildEnvironment
from sphinx.transforms import SphinxTransform
from sphinx.util import logging

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 10):
        from typing import TypeGuard
    else:
        from typing_extensions import TypeGuard

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

GITHUB_API_URL = "https://api.github.com/repos/{0.project}/issues/{1}"


class IssueTrackerBuildEnvironment(BuildEnvironment):
    tracker_config: "TrackerConfig"
    issuetracker_cache: "IssueTrackerCache"
    github_rate_limit: t.Tuple[float, bool]


class Issue(t.NamedTuple):
    id: str
    title: str
    url: str
    closed: bool


IssueTrackerCache = t.Dict[str, Issue]


@dataclasses.dataclass
class TrackerConfig:
    project: str
    url: str

    """
    Issue tracker configuration.
    This class provides configuration for trackers, and is passed as
    ``tracker_config`` arguments to callbacks of
    :event:`issuetracker-lookup-issue`.
    """

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        if self.url is not None:
            self.url = self.url.rstrip("/")

    @classmethod
    def from_sphinx_config(cls, config: Config) -> "TrackerConfig":
        """
        Get tracker configuration from ``config``.
        """
        project = config.issuetracker_project or config.project
        url = config.issuetracker_url
        return cls(project=project, url=url)


class PendingIssueXRef(pending_xref):
    tracker_config: TrackerConfig


class IssueReferences(SphinxTransform):

    default_priority = 999

    def apply(self) -> None:
        config = self.document.settings.env.config
        tracker_config = TrackerConfig.from_sphinx_config(config)
        issue_pattern = config.issuetracker_issue_pattern
        title_template = None
        if isinstance(issue_pattern, str):
            issue_pattern = re.compile(issue_pattern)
        for node in self.document.traverse(nodes.Text):
            parent = node.parent
            if isinstance(parent, (nodes.literal, nodes.FixedTextElement)):
                # ignore inline and block literal text
                continue
            if isinstance(parent, nodes.reference):
                continue
            text = str(node)
            new_nodes = []
            last_issue_ref_end = 0
            for match in issue_pattern.finditer(text):
                # catch invalid pattern with too many groups
                if len(match.groups()) != 1:
                    raise ValueError(
                        "issuetracker_issue_pattern must have "
                        "exactly one group: {0!r}".format(match.groups())
                    )
                # extract the text between the last issue reference and the
                # current issue reference and put it into a new text node
                head = text[last_issue_ref_end : match.start()]
                if head:
                    new_nodes.append(nodes.Text(head))
                # adjust the position of the last issue reference in the
                # text
                last_issue_ref_end = match.end()
                # extract the issue text (including the leading dash)
                issuetext = match.group(0)
                # extract the issue number (excluding the leading dash)
                issue_id = match.group(1)
                # turn the issue reference into a reference node
                refnode = PendingIssueXRef()

                refnode["refdomain"] = None
                refnode["reftarget"] = issue_id
                refnode["reftype"] = "issue"
                refnode["trackerconfig"] = tracker_config
                reftitle = title_template or issuetext
                refnode.append(
                    nodes.inline(issuetext, reftitle, classes=["xref", "issue"])
                )
                new_nodes.append(refnode)
            if not new_nodes:
                # no issue references were found, move on to the next node
                continue
            # extract the remaining text after the last issue reference, and
            # put it into a text node
            tail = text[last_issue_ref_end:]
            if tail:
                new_nodes.append(nodes.Text(tail))
            # find and remove the original node, and insert all new nodes
            # instead
            parent.replace(node, new_nodes)


def is_issuetracker_env(
    env: t.Any,
) -> "TypeGuard['IssueTrackerBuildEnvironment']":
    return hasattr(env, "issuetracker_cache") and env.issuetracker_cache is not None


def lookup_issue(
    app: Sphinx, tracker_config: TrackerConfig, issue_id: str
) -> t.Optional[Issue]:
    """
    Lookup the given issue.
    The issue is first looked up in an internal cache.  If it is not found, the
    event ``issuetracker-lookup-issue`` is emitted.  The result of this
    invocation is then cached and returned.
    ``app`` is the sphinx application object.  ``tracker_config`` is the
    :class:`TrackerConfig` object representing the issue tracker configuration.
    ``issue_id`` is a string containing the issue id.
    Return a :class:`Issue` object for the issue with the given ``issue_id``,
    or ``None`` if the issue wasn't found.
    """
    env = app.env
    if is_issuetracker_env(env):
        cache: IssueTrackerCache = env.issuetracker_cache
        if issue_id not in cache:
            issue = app.emit_firstresult(
                "issuetracker-lookup-issue", tracker_config, issue_id
            )
            cache[issue_id] = issue
        return cache[issue_id]
    return None


def lookup_issues(app: Sphinx, doctree: nodes.document) -> None:
    """
    Lookup issues found in the given ``doctree``.
    Each issue reference in the given ``doctree`` is looked up.  Each lookup
    result is cached by mapping the referenced issue id to the looked up
    :class:`Issue` object (an existing issue) or ``None`` (a missing issue).
    The cache is available at ``app.env.issuetracker_cache`` and is pickled
    along with the environment.
    """
    for node in doctree.traverse(PendingIssueXRef):
        if node["reftype"] == "issue":
            lookup_issue(app, node["trackerconfig"], node["reftarget"])


def make_issue_reference(issue: Issue, content_node: nodes.inline) -> nodes.reference:
    """
    Create a reference node for the given issue.
    ``content_node`` is a docutils node which is supposed to be added as
    content of the created reference.  ``issue`` is the :class:`Issue` which
    the reference shall point to.
    Return a :class:`docutils.nodes.reference` for the issue.
    """
    reference = nodes.reference()
    reference["refuri"] = issue.url
    if issue.title:
        reference["reftitle"] = issue.title
    if issue.closed:
        content_node["classes"].append("closed")
    reference.append(content_node)
    return reference


def resolve_issue_reference(
    app: Sphinx, env: BuildEnvironment, node: PendingIssueXRef, contnode: nodes.inline
) -> t.Optional[nodes.reference]:
    """
    Resolve an issue reference and turn it into a real reference to the
    corresponding issue.
    ``app`` and ``env`` are the Sphinx application and environment
    respectively.  ``node`` is a ``pending_xref`` node representing the missing
    reference.  It is expected to have the following attributes:
    - ``reftype``: The reference type
    - ``trackerconfig``: The :class:`TrackerConfig`` to use for this node
    - ``reftarget``: The issue id
    - ``classes``: The node classes
    References with a ``reftype`` other than ``'issue'`` are skipped by
    returning ``None``.  Otherwise the new node is returned.
    If the referenced issue was found, a real reference to this issue is
    returned.  The text of this reference is formatted with the :class:`Issue`
    object available in the ``issue`` key.  The reference title is set to the
    issue title.  If the issue is closed, the class ``closed`` is added to the
    new content node.
    Otherwise, if the issue was not found, the content node is returned.
    """
    if node["reftype"] != "issue":
        return None

    issue = lookup_issue(app, node["trackerconfig"], node["reftarget"])
    if issue is None:
        return contnode
    else:
        classes = contnode["classes"]
        conttext = str(contnode[0])
        formatted_conttext = nodes.Text(conttext.format(issue=issue))
        formatted_contnode = nodes.inline(conttext, formatted_conttext, classes=classes)
        assert issue is not None
        return make_issue_reference(issue, formatted_contnode)
    return None


def init_cache(app: Sphinx) -> None:
    if not hasattr(app.env, "issuetracker_cache"):
        app.env.issuetracker_cache: "IssueTrackerCache" = {}  # type: ignore
    return None


def check_project_with_username(tracker_config: TrackerConfig) -> None:
    if "/" not in tracker_config.project:
        raise ValueError(
            "username missing in project name: {0.project}".format(tracker_config)
        )


HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "sphinxcontrib-issuetracker v{0}".format("1.0")}


def get(app: Sphinx, url: str) -> t.Optional[requests.Response]:
    """
    Get a response from the given ``url``.
    ``url`` is a string containing the URL to request via GET. ``app`` is the
    Sphinx application object.
    Return the :class:`~requests.Response` object on status code 200, or
    ``None`` otherwise. If the status code is not 200 or 404, a warning is
    emitted via ``app``.
    """
    response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        return response
    elif response.status_code != requests.codes.not_found:
        msg = "GET {0.url} failed with code {0.status_code}"
        logger.warning(msg.format(response))

    return None


def lookup_github_issue(
    app: Sphinx, tracker_config: TrackerConfig, issue_id: str
) -> t.Optional[Issue]:
    check_project_with_username(tracker_config)

    env = app.env
    if is_issuetracker_env(env):
        # Get rate limit information from the environment
        timestamp, limit_hit = getattr(env, "github_rate_limit", (0, False))

        if limit_hit and time.time() - timestamp > 3600:
            # Github limits applications hourly
            limit_hit = False

        if not limit_hit:
            url = GITHUB_API_URL.format(tracker_config, issue_id)
            response = get(app, url)
            if response:
                rate_remaining = response.headers.get("X-RateLimit-Remaining")
                assert rate_remaining is not None
                if rate_remaining.isdigit() and int(rate_remaining) == 0:
                    logger.warning("Github rate limit hit")
                    env.github_rate_limit = (time.time(), True)
                issue = response.json()
                closed = issue["state"] == "closed"
                return Issue(
                    id=issue_id,
                    title=issue["title"],
                    closed=closed,
                    url=issue["html_url"],
                )
        else:
            logger.warning(
                "Github rate limit exceeded, not resolving issue {0}".format(issue_id)
            )
    return None


BUILTIN_ISSUE_TRACKERS: t.Dict[str, t.Any] = {
    "github": lookup_github_issue,
}


def init_transformer(app: Sphinx) -> None:
    if app.config.issuetracker_plaintext_issues:
        app.add_transform(IssueReferences)


def connect_builtin_tracker(app: Sphinx) -> None:
    if app.config.issuetracker:
        tracker = BUILTIN_ISSUE_TRACKERS[app.config.issuetracker.lower()]
        app.connect(str("issuetracker-lookup-issue"), tracker)


def setup(app: Sphinx) -> t.Dict[str, t.Any]:
    app.add_config_value("mybase", "https://github.com/cihai/unihan-etl", "env")
    app.add_event(str("issuetracker-lookup-issue"))
    app.connect(str("builder-inited"), connect_builtin_tracker)
    app.add_config_value("issuetracker", None, "env")
    app.add_config_value("issuetracker_project", None, "env")
    app.add_config_value("issuetracker_url", None, "env")
    # configuration specific to plaintext issue references
    app.add_config_value("issuetracker_plaintext_issues", True, "env")
    app.add_config_value(
        "issuetracker_issue_pattern",
        re.compile(
            r"#(\d+)",
        ),
        "env",
    )
    app.add_config_value("issuetracker_title_template", None, "env")
    app.connect(str("builder-inited"), init_cache)
    app.connect(str("builder-inited"), init_transformer)
    app.connect(str("doctree-read"), lookup_issues)
    app.connect(str("missing-reference"), resolve_issue_reference)
    return {
        "version": "1.0",
        "parallel_read_safe": True,
        "parallel_write_safe": True,
    }
```

### Mirrors

- https://gist.github.com/tony/05a3043d97d37c158763fb2f6a2d5392
- https://github.com/ignatenkobrain/sphinxcontrib-issuetracker/issues/25

### Mypy users

`mypy --strict docs/_ext/link_issues.py` work as of mypy 0.971

If you use mypy: `pip install types-docutils types-requests`

Install:

- https://pypi.org/project/types-docutils/
- https://pypi.org/project/types-requests/
- https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/ (Python <3.10)

### Example

via [unihan-etl#261](https://github.com/cihai/unihan-etl/pull/261) / [v0.17.2](https://github.com/cihai/unihan-etl/tree/v0.17.2) ([source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cihai/unihan-etl/v0.17.2/CHANGES), [view, but page may be outdated](https://unihan-etl.git-pull.com/history.html#unihan-etl-0-17-2-2022-08-21))

[image: Example of markdown and sphinx-rendered page]